# Пролаги при старте программы из-за сети (qt)

Tags: c++, qt, сеть

При старте приложения в 80% случаев происходит лаг на 5-10 секунд если в приложении используется сеть (QNetworkAccessManager)

В начале думал что причина из-за openSSL (использовал сборку по умолчанию) подсунул нужные dll ошибки пропали но лаг не пропал.. Попробовал собрать комплект из исходников с ключами --no-ssl и --static лаг остался.

Решил что дело в коде но если использовать в qml картинку (Image) и указать source на что-то на подобии http://site.com/img.png то также будет лаг. Единственное что смог нагуглить это дефайн QT_NO_BEARERMANAGEMENT но результат тотже, в 80% случаев лаг.

Сделал костыль при запуске в отдельном потоке делается запрос, и пока он не выполнится программа не запускается.
Но хотелось бы убрать этот костыль в чем дело и куда дальше рыть не пойму. Какая причина может быть подобного лага?

Comment: Может у вас эти картинки подгружаются синхронно?

Comment: На QT с сетью я не работал, но предположу, что инициализация соединения и загрузка картинки требует времени. У вас точно не всегда происходит лаг?

Comment: Я тоже думаю что дело в какой-то инициализации, лаг происходит в 80% случаев.. а также если программа не чего не делала мин 30 то опять будет лаг. причем не важно что я хочу от сети. сделать get запрос через http или подгрузить картинку/xml через qml.

Comment: Думаю в вопросе @VTT и кроется ваш ответ. Сеть это очень непредсказуемая область. Сложно с уверенностью говорить что происходит между уровнями и как ходят пакеты по сети. В Android уже давно нельзя работать с сетью из потока с gui что бы не было лагов. Отсюда можно сказать что ваш "костыль" вовсе не костыль, а правильная реализация работы с сетью.

Comment: Оставлю здесь код может поможет кому сэкономить кучу времени
https://hello-site.ru/share/web-request1/

Comment: @Navira, все правильно вы сделали. Тяжелую работу лучше оформлять в отдельном потоке. Почитайте про многопоточность и MVVP/MVP/MVC (Главное не сами виды архитектуры, а способ "разделение ответственности".